# Not able to save nls.fit (multiline text) data through R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

An empty file without the nls.fit data gets created when the following code is used in a R Shiny app. However, the nls.fit data gets saved when attempted through a regular R script. What am I missing here?

```
df <- data.frame(xdata = c(1000.00,300.00,100.00,30.00,10.00,3.00,1.00,0.30,
                           0.10,0.03,0.01,0.00),
                 ydata = c(91.8,95.3,100,123,203,620,1210,1520,1510,1520,1590,
                           1620))

nls.fit <- nls(ydata ~ (ymax*xdata / (ec50 + xdata)) + Ns*xdata + ymin, data=df,
               start=list(ymax=1624.75, ymin = 91.85, ec50 = 3, Ns = 0.2045514))

sink("sink-examp.txt")
nls.fit
sink()
```

Comment: Try `print(nls.fit)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @G.Grothendieck, the following code worked in R Shiny app to save the nls.fit data as a text file.

```
sink("NLS_Fit.txt")
print(nls.fit)
sink()
```